# Dynamic LinkButton is not firing anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

We have a Sharepoint 2013 project. There is drawer content web part that can be added to pages and can create pages. The problem is that is is no longer deleting in drawers when you click the the Delete Item LinkButton. This the code to build out the drawer:

```
protected HtmlGenericControl BuildDisplayContent()
        {
            Items.Sort();

            var container = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            container.Attributes["class"] = "drawers drawers-multiple-levels";

            foreach (var contentItem in Items)
            {
                var drawerGroup = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                drawerGroup.Attributes["class"] = "drawer-group";

                //subheader
                var subheaderWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                subheaderWrapper.Attributes["class"] = "subheader-wrapper";

                var subheaderContainer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                subheaderContainer.Attributes["class"] = "subheader-container";

                var subheaderH3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
                subheaderH3.Attributes["class"] = "subheader";
                subheaderH3.InnerHtml = contentItem.Header;

                subheaderContainer.Controls.Add(subheaderH3);
                subheaderWrapper.Controls.Add(subheaderContainer);
                drawerGroup.Controls.Add(subheaderWrapper);

                //drawer content
                var drawer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                drawer.InnerHtml = contentItem.Content;

                if (contentItem.Children == null || contentItem.Children.Count == 0)
                {
                    drawer.Attributes["class"] = "drawer";
                }
                else
                {
                    drawer.Attributes["class"] = "drawer drawer-with-subdrawers";

                    //fill child controls
                    contentItem.Children.Sort();

                    foreach (var child in contentItem.Children)
                    {
                        var childSubheaderH4 = new HtmlGenericControl("h4");
                        childSubheaderH4.Attributes["class"] = "subheader-second-level text-ca";
                        childSubheaderH4.InnerHtml = child.Header;
                        drawer.Controls.Add(childSubheaderH4);

                        var childDrawer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        childDrawer.Attributes["class"] = child.IsTwoColumn ? "drawer drawer-second-level two-column" : "drawer drawer-second-level";
                        childDrawer.InnerHtml = child.Content;
                        drawer.Controls.Add(childDrawer);
                    }
                }

                drawerGroup.Controls.Add(drawer);

                var drawerBottom = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                drawerBottom.Attributes["class"] = "drawer-bottom";

                drawerGroup.Controls.Add(drawerBottom);
                container.Controls.Add(drawerGroup);
            }

            return container;
        }
```

This method is being called in the OnLoad method to build out the drawer content.

This the click event:

```
void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var button = (LinkButton)sender;
            var path = button.Attributes["ItemPath"].Split('-');

            if(path.Length == 1) {
                items.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(path[0]));

                var c = 0;
                foreach (var item in items)
                    item.Ordinal = c++;

            } else if(path.Length == 2) {
                ((DrawerContentItem)Items[Convert.ToInt32(path[0])]).Children.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(path[1]));

                var c = 0;
                foreach (var item in ((DrawerContentItem)Items[Convert.ToInt32(path[0])]).Children)
                    item.Ordinal = c++;
            }

            try
            {
                var storageKey = Manager.GetStorageKey(this);
                Manager.SaveChanges(storageKey);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var child = new Label();
                child.Text = ex.Message;
                this.Controls.Add(child);
            }

            BuildEditContent(control.BodyContentEdit.Controls);
        }
```

We've been trying to figure what could cause this to stop working. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying the DeleteButton_Click is not firing when the button is pressed?  Was it  ever firing?  And is the front end code wired up to this event correctly?

Comment: Yes, when I press the linkbutton. I was working before. This is the front-end code.

Comment: <div class="neutral channel <%= DrawersCssClass %> neutral-secondary-spring-spring drawer-content">
    <div class="channel-inner-padding">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhContentEdit" runat="server" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhContentDisplay" runat="server" />
    <!--<asp:Panel ID="plhNoContent" runat="server" />-->
    </div>
</div>